# Scala Edit Erase

Tags: scala

I have a series of tests that need to pass, one of the is edit erase.

```
/**
   * Edit Erase  (forward delete).  Delete the character to the right of the
   * cursor. If the cursor is at the end of the buffer then ignore this command
   * (there is no character to the right of the cursor). If deletion succeeds
   * then do not change the cursor position.  The marker position is not
   * changed UNLESS the deletion has caused it to point beyond the end of the
   * (updated) buffer. In this case make the marker equal to end.
   */
```

The Marker and Cursor are Int and the buffer is a string.

What I need to do is if the cursor is the end (buffer.length) then the command needs to be ignored, but the bit which I'm stuck on is making the marker move to the end only if the deleting has caused the marker to be greater than the buffer length.

I have written some code but are there any suggestions on this?

```
def ee() {
  if(cursor != end) {
    buffer.delete(cursor,cursor+ 1) 
    if(marker > end) 
      marker = buffer.length
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not really updating the value of `end` anywhere. You are also not moving your cursor. And the indexes for array, buffer etc in Scala start at 0. So you probably want `marker = buffer.length - 1`.

Comment: Also, this question is really not something which fits on StackOverflow.